# How to open pdf files under cursor (using 'gf') with external PDF readers in vim

Tags: vim, autocmd

The current <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> command will open *.pdf files as ascii text. I want the pdf file opened with external tools (like okular, foxitreader, etc.). I tried to use autocmd to achieve it like this:

```
au BufReadCmd *.pdf silent !FoxitReader % & "open file under cursor with FoxitReader
au BufEnter *.pdf <Ctrl-O> "since we do not really open the file, go back to the previous buffer
```

However, the second autocmd failed to work as expected. I could not figure out a way to execute `<Ctrl-o>` command in a `autocmd` way.

Could anyone give me a hint on how to `<Ctrl-O>` in `autocmd`, or just directly suggest a better way to open pdf files with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That's because what follows an `autocmd` is an ex command (the ones beginning
with a colon). To simulate the execution of a normal mode command, use the
[`:normal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#%3anormal) command. The problem is that you can't pass a `<C-O>` (and not
`<Ctrl-O>`) directly to `:normal`, it will be taken as literal characters (<,
then C, then r) which is not a very meaningful normal command. You have two
options:

#### 1.Insert a literal ^O Character

Use <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to get one:

```
au BufEnter *.pdf normal! ^O
```

#### 2.Use [`:execute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#%3aexe) to Build Your Command

This way you can get a more readable result with the escaped sequence:

```
au BufEnter *.pdf exe "normal! \<c-o>"
```

Anyway, this is not the most appropriate command. `<C-O>` just jumps to the
previous location in the jump list, so your buffer remains opened. I would do
something like:

```
au BufEnter *.pdf bdelete
```

Instead. Still I have another solution for you.

---

Create another command with a map, say <kbd>gO</kbd>. Then use your PDF reader
directly, or a utility like `open` if you're in MacOS X or Darwin (not sure if
other Unix systems have it, and how it's called). It's just like double clicking
the icon of the file passed as argument, so it will open your default PDF reader
or any other application configured to open any file by default, like images or
so.

```
:nnoremap gO :!open <cfile><CR>
```

This `<cfile>` will be expanded to the file under the cursor. So if you want to
open the file in Vim, use <kbd>gf</kbd>. If you want to open it with the default
application, use <kbd>gO</kbd>.

If you don't have this command or prefer a PDF-only solution, create a map to
your preferred command:

```
:nnoremap gO :!FoxitReader <cfile> &<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion with autocmd works. However, when I tried the 'gO' solution with FoxitReader (I did not find equivalent program of open in my Linux distro), the FoxitReader just reported "The file could not be found". It seems the <cfile> had not been expanded correctly. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Glad to help @Liang! In the situation where the `gO` isn't working, does `gf` work? With `<cfile>` it is supposed to be the same. It's possible that the file isn't in the current directory you're in, or something like that.

Comment: It does related to path issue! However, `gf` does not suffer from the issue, while `gO` does. In my case, I had a bibtex file in `~/papers/library.bib`, and all pdf files were located in the same directory of `papers`. When I opened the bib file from `$HOME`, `gf` worked and `gO` failed; When I opened it from `papers` directory, both solutions worked.

Comment: unfortunately the `gO` solution has issues when working with filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: The window-deleting behavior of `:bdelete` was unacceptable to me, and I switched to https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-bufkill (it deletes buffers without closing windows).

Answer (score 0):

If the default app is acceptable, then simply using `:!open %` in **command** mode works. You can always map this to a suitable leader combination in your vim config file etc.

If you want something that works with **normal** mode, then you could try something like the following (i use this too for opening HTML files), and modify to your own needs:

`if has('win32') || has ('win64')
  autocmd FileType html  nmap <Leader>g :silent ! start firefox "%"<cr>
elseif has('mac')
  autocmd FileType html  nmap <Leader>g :!open "%"<cr><cr>
endif`

Comment: I used `:nnoremap gO :!xdg-open <cfile><CR>` and it's opening files with the default associated application, but not files with a `@` in the path eg `~/jim@webaddress.mail/paper.pdf` It only captures the bit after the `@`. `help <cfile>` does not say much. Quotes around `<cfile>`, like this `"<cfile>"` don't help. Any ideas?